# +document.getElementByClassName('balance') returning NaN even though value on website in a number

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, scripting

Im making a script on in the console. And when i try use the command +document.getElementByClassName('balance') it returns NaN. The element im trying to get is a number and in the inspect element it looks like this -->

```
<span class="amount">0</span>
```

Does anyone have any ideas to get this element to return as a number.
Thanks!

Comment: @madox2 Wrong in two ways.

Comment: @madox2 it still returns NaN

Comment: This comment didn't make sense. lol

Comment: the answer below worked percetly: +document.getElementsByClassName('amount')[0].textContent

Comment: @OrryVandermeulen that isn't even a valid thing JavaScript.

Comment: Why do all my questions get like -2? Is it getting down voted. I dont understand. Im really new on here.

Answer (score 1):

First of all it's `getElementsByClassName`, but even then you can't just convert an HTMLSpanElement object to a number and expect it to work.

```
+document.getElementsByClassName('amount')[0].textContent
```

This will get the element, assuming it's the first one with that class name (you'd be better off with an ID really), gets its text content ("0") and converts it to a number.

Comment: That doesn't work now. I changed the balance and now its returning cannot read text property of text content?